# How to find the root of a polynomial function closest to the initial guess?

Tags: numerical-methods, nonlinear-optimization, newton-raphson

I need some easy to implement and fast numerical method that finds the root of a nonlinear function (a polynomial in my case) closest to my initial guess. If I know that there is one root $x^\star_k\in I$ and I start in the middle of $I$, is there a numerical method that guarantees convergence to exactly this root?

Newton's method does not seem to assure that I stay within the interval since it may converge to a zero further away outside the interval, right? Can I modify Newton's Method $x_{n+1}=x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$ somehow to assure I stay within the interval?

Or, maybe it is not possible at all with Newton's Method but with the Bisection method instead, although at slower pace?

More precisely, I have a 5 to 10th degree polynomial and want to find all roots but know approximately where the roots are, that is, I divided the x-range into intervals $I_k\subseteq X$ that contain only one root $x^\star_k\in I_k$. 
I further have some regularity assumption on my function (no infinite derivatives etc).

Thanks in advance for our help.

Comment: How do you certify that there is exactly one root in each of the intervals?

Comment: I don't really. Just in practice I can indeed make simplifying assumptions on the number and distance of the zeros (well-spaced over whole range) since what I have is a polynomial over some small interval. Of course, this is not entirely safe but I'm not sure if there would be a feasible (fast, easy to implement) method without these assumptions.

Answer (score 4):

You can combine bisection and Newton method very efficiently. If you go to [this place](http://astronu.jinr.ru/wiki/images/8/8c/NumericalRecipesinF77.pdf), on page 359, you will find subroutine RTSAFE ([here](http://iop.vast.ac.vn/~nvthanh/cours/numerical_methods/code/CH2_newton_BS.f) and [here](http://adh.usace.army.mil/svn/adh/PT123/trunk/src/util/rtsafe.f)) which does exactly what you want. It is very robust.

I apologize for giving you a reference to Fortran coding. If you can access the books of Numerical Recipes, you will find the equivalent in C and C++.

Comment: There is C code here: http://www.aip.de/groups/soe/local/numres/bookcpdf/c9-4.pdf

Comment: Thanks, this (especially the code) helped me a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding "easy to implement", I would recommend that you use a root-finding function written by an expert, rather than writing your own. That's certainly easier, and will probably lead to better results.

The algorithms in the "Numerical Recipes" books are typically pretty good, though they favor simplicity over optimality.

If you really want to write your own root-finder ...

Newton's method can be adapted to stay within a given interval that's known to contain a root. Look up "root bracketing".

Alternatively, use the Secant Method, instead of Newton's method. Its theoretical rate of convergence is almost as fast and it naturally preserves root bracketing.

For a fascinating analysis (and a glimpse at some of the difficulties involved), take a look at [these notes](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/Math128/RealRoots.pdf) by a leading expert.

It's also worth mentioning that there are specialized methods for finding roots of polynomials. One of the best approaches is to [find the eigenvalues of the polynomial's companion matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20033494/root-finding-with-companion-matrix). Again, I would not recommend that you write your own software for finding eigenvalues; use proven existing code (e.g. Linpack, etc.) instead.

Comment: I agree finding the eigenvalues of the polynomial's companion matrix might be the most elegant and precise, however I don't have the time now to implement it. I guess even though I could use an other software for finding eigenvalues, it would still involve more work than bisection/Newton method.

Comment: Do you know whether the companion matrix eigenvalue based method can be generalised to multi-variate polynomials?

Comment: I don't know if the companion matrix method extends to multivariate polynomials. Probably not. Bisection/Newton will probably work fine. But, again, I don't recommend that you code it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The middle between Newton's method and Bisection is the regula falsi or false position method. See wikipedia for details and anti-stalling methods that make this method only slightly slower as the secant method while retaining the convergence guarantees of a bracketed method.

```
from math import abs

def illinois(f,a,b, tol):
    '''regula falsi resp. false postion method with the Illinois anti-stalling variation'''
    # b is the (theoretically) best point, 
    # a the last computed point with opposite sign of f(a)
    fa = f(a)
    fb = f(b)
    if abs(fb)>abs(fa): a,fa,b,fb = b,fb,a,fa
    while(abs(b-a)>tol*(abs(a)+abs(b))):
        # c = (a*fb-b*fa)/(fb-fa) # this while symmetric may become numerically unstable
        c = b - fb * (b-a)/(fb-fa)
        fc = f(c)
        if fa*fc < 0: # interval end might stall away from root
            fa *= 0.5 # decrease weight of b, move midpoint towards a
        else: # [b, c] is the new bracketing interval 
            a = b; fa = fb

        b = c; fb = fc
    return b, fb
```

If the initial $[a,b]$ is not a proper bracketing interval, this will replicate the secant method until points with opposing sign are found. In this stage, points outside the initial interval may be encountered.

Comment: +1! Though, I fixed a couple typos so that it would run. Why the import of `abs` from `math`? There's a built in already.

Comment: Over-coutious. In the source I had `numpy.abs`, which then is also not necessary.

Comment: Wikipedia says it's only for a function in one variable. Just out of interest, could this method or Newton method with root bracketing or Newton method with bisection extended to multi-variate root finding, or is it a much more complicated problem?

Comment: Alone the bracketing is complicated to extend. In the complex case you got, as analogon of the sign change, the winding number which is equal to the number of contained roots. However, in the general two-dimensional case, the sign of a simple root can be +1 or -1, so that winding numbers or higher-dimensional generalizations (Chern classes) do not translate directly to root numbers.

Comment: Broyden and adjoint Broyden generalize the secant method. Branch-and-Bound might be seen as a generalization to Bisection, but suffers the curse of dimensionality. -- As for bracketed Newton, restarting from a random point inside the bounds if the Newton iteration leaves those bounds might be the simplest strategy.

Comment: Ok, thank you. So I get from your answer that it's possible in higher dimensions but complexity increases exponentially (makes sense). I still expected it to be generalisable quite easily to higher dimensions: Newton methods find the root if started close enough (+ regularity assumptions) with quadratic convergence rate. "Checking" that it stays within the multi-dimensional interval seems an easy enough task for me. But I haven't really had time to think about it.

Comment: Look for "sequential quadratic programming" and general "trust-region methods" for additional inspiration. -- By hear-say, with increasing dimension the regions of quadratic convergence rapidly decrease and the fractal boundaries between the attraction sets become more chaotic, with increasing possibilities for regions of no convergence thrown in. Carefully selected homotopies can sometimes help with that.